# Specifying Joomla Menu Classes

Tags: joomla-3.x, css

I am attempting to use a Text Separator as a non-clickable menu parent header.  Unfortunately the template I am using formats this differently to the clickable menu items, so I would like to modify the CSS to give it the same look and feel.
Firebug tells me the class for a clickable item is of the form class="item-102 deeper parent" I wonder if someone could explain where I can find the CSS code for these classes and how I might apply the relevant parts to a Text Separator.
(I have searched the styles.css file for my template and cannot find it).

Answer (score 2):

The location will vary depending on your template.
To find what's being applied and where, I'd probably uninstall Firebug and use the Firefox DevTools (as Firebug suggest users do as they no longer develop Firebug).

To do this, click the menu item with the DevTools' `Inspector` and look in the right `Rules` column of your console. This will show you what styles are being applied.  To the right of the style it will say something like `style.css:76` - which means it is on line 76 of `style.css`.

A Text Separator has the class `divider`.